# How to set more than one handler through config file in python?

Tags: python, logging, configuration-files

I know you can set more than one logger handler with different level by calling `addHandler` in Python.

However, I need to set two handlers through a config file, so that by calling

```
logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

I get a `logger` that have two handlers for different level.

How should I write the `log.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example with the root logger having two handlers:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=hand01,hand02

[formatters]
keys=

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=hand01,hand02

[handler_hand01]
class=StreamHandler
args=()

[handler_hand02]
class=StreamHandler
args=()
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to set hand01 and hand02 for different levels, i.e., INFO and WARNING?

Comment: @SpiritZhang: Just add `level=INFO` to the appropriate handler section.